# Django handling multiple apps in a same project

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Lately I started a Django project, I created an app and started to add my models and views in it, as time passed the project get bigger and bigger, more than 20 models, serializations, and a huge views file containing thousands of code lines was the result, in the other hand some of the models (like user profile) might be useful in other projects as well, so I decided to create some new apps (like userProfile) and move related codes to my new app.

So I did the following process :

1. Using manage.py >> startapp userProfile
2. cut the models , serializers , ... from main app and past them into new app models.py , serializers.py, ...
3. added userProfile into settings.py installed apps

At this point lots of problem occurred as UserProfile model and serializers was not available in the main app anymore, so I tried to import them from new reference (userProfie app) but the code `from userProfile.models import Userprofile` is not working and it seems that the main app can't see the userProfile app.

PS: if I write `from PROJECTNAME.userProfile.models import UserProfile` , no IDE error occurs but at the time of building project an "Module not found error" shows up

Comment: ensure to rerun `migrate` and `makemigrations` again. Also ensure that your settings.py include the correct os oath and static url as well as the correct import methods within your files.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I finally found was to export my apps (like userProfile) as a packages and then install those packages in my project, I used the Article on Django website "[How to write reusable apps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/reusable-apps/#:%7E:text=Check%20out%20Django%20Packages%20for,that%20make%20your%20project%20unique.)" for that, however this is a good solution but it has a downside which is

> the package is somehow an external resource and is not meant to be
> edited in the project

, I mean if you need a change you should have to edit the package somewhere else and then `pip install --upgrade YourPackage` in the project.